# Using JavaScript to control mp3 playback in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, audio, script-tag

I am trying to control an mp3 through click events.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<audio id="demo" autoplay="true" hidden="hidden">
   <source src="Lute.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
   Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<div onmousedown="WhichButton(event)">
  <img src="Birch-Forest.jpg" alt="A birch forest in the fall"
  style="width:600px;height:572px">
</div>

<script>
var playing = false;
function WhichButton(event) {
    if (event.button == 0) {
    document.getElementById('demo').volume-=0.1;
    }
    else if (event.button == 1 && playing) {
    document.getElementById('demo').pause;
    } 
    else if (event.button == 1 && !playing) {
    document.getElementById('demo').play;
    } 
    else if (event.button == 2) {
    document.getElementById('demo').volume+=0.1;
    } 
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This code loads the image and starts audio playback, but the controls do not work. I don't really know what I'm doing, just a beginner in HTML and JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some errors in your script... let's see:

1. You initialize the `playing` variable as **false**, but your audioplayer has autoplay set on true... so maybe, just for clarity, your variable should be initialize to **true** or renamed to *pausing*. However this is not an error :)
2. The `pause` and `play` are **functions** of your audioplayer so if you wanna invoke them you have to use the *parenthesis*, like this: `document.getElementById('demo').pause();`. Vice versa `volume`is a **property** so you don't need the parenthesis.
3. Now, you want to play the audio when it is paused and pause it when it is playing. Correctly you have a boolean variable for this (playing), but you never change its value!

Your code with some corrections:

```
<script>
var playing = true; // Point 1
var audioPlayer = document.getElementById('demo');
function WhichButton(event) {       
    if (event.button == 0 && audioPlayer.volume > 0) {
        audioPlayer.volume-=0.1;
    }
    else if (event.button == 1 && playing) {
        audioPlayer.pause(); // Point 2
        playing = false; // Point 3
    } 
    else if (event.button == 1 && !playing) {
        audioPlayer.play();
        playing = true;
    } 
    else if (event.button == 2 && audioPlayer.volume < 1) {
        audioPlayer.volume+=0.1;
    }   
}
</script>
```

Comment: This was really helpful! Thank you! Although the right click doesn't really work, but I chose that button. :)